# Java string Util - Split the String with space

Tags: java

If i'm sending the string with numberic to below code, its returning with % symbol.

**Example :**

`st1a - st%a` Why numeric replacing with % here ? but if stack overflow , its coming up with stack as string and overflow as another string.

Please advise.

```
String aName =StringUtils.lowerCase(Number.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "%"));
```

Comment: Can you give a real example of something you want to parse. I don't see the point of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please write several examples with sample input and expected output, it'll be much more clear than trying to explain in words what you want

Comment: The code you've provided will not produce `"qw%ant"` from `"qw23ant"`. It produces `"qw%%ant"`. Post an actual example of what you're trying, along with your intended output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to split the string around a space, use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] splitName = "qw234 ant".split(" "); // Produces {"qw234", "ant"}
```

Or you can treat runs of consecutive whitespace characters as a single delimiter, since `split` takes a regex:

```
String[] splitName = "qw234          ant".split("\\s+"); // Produces {"qw234", "ant"}
```

To fully understand what `split` is doing, take a look at the documentation in the link above, so you can modify this to split your strings however you like. I can't tell what else you might be asking, so without clarification, this is the best I can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all spaces anywhere in a string (at the start, at the end, in the middle) try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newString[] = "qw23ant".split(23)
```

This should split your string into two parts, "qw" and, "ant" and save them in a string array, "newstring"